# Trying to read MJPEG header in C#

Tags: c#, http, stream, mjpeg, dotnet-httpclient

Is anyone familiar with a way to extract the header in an MJPEG file sent through HTTP protocol?  I've come across HttpClient class in C# but I'm inexperienced with it and I haven't seen any examples with MJPEG streams.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a specialist, but I have read as a broad view that a MJPEG stream is a flow of single JPEG pictures enclosed in two bytes: FFD8 and FFD9.

Using optimized bare C# bricks like arrays, tests and loops, you can parse a stream returned by a call to HttpClient to peel its JPEG frames off.

Here is something fast, simple and stupid that show a stream. The only fancies are the use of HttpClient and its async functions:

```
async static Task Start(string url, Action<byte[]> action, int bufSize = 1024, CancellationToken? tk = null) {

    var myTk = tk.HasValue ? tk.Value : CancellationToken.None;

    using(var cli = new HttpClient()) {

        var streamBuffer = new byte[bufSize];

        // Give it the maximum size in bytes of your picture
        var frameBuffer = new List<byte>(1024 * 1024);

        var ff = false;
        var inPic = false;

        using(var stream = await cli.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false)) {

            while(!myTk.IsCancellationRequested) {

                var l = await stream.ReadAsync(streamBuffer, 0, bufSize).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var idx = 0;

                while(idx < l) {
                    var c = streamBuffer[idx++];

                    // We have found a FF
                    if(c == 0xff) {
                        ff = true;
                    }
                    // We found a JPEG picture start
                    else if(ff && c == 0xd8) {
                        frameBuffer.Clear();
                        frameBuffer.Add(0xff);
                        frameBuffer.Add(0xd8);
                        if(inPic) {
                            Console.WriteLine("Skipped frame : end expected");
                        }
                        ff = false;
                        inPic = true;
                    }
                    // We found a JPEG picture end
                    else if(ff && c == 0xd9) {
                        frameBuffer.Add(0xff);
                        frameBuffer.Add(0xd9);

                        // Send the JPEG picture as an event
                        action(frameBuffer.ToArray());

                        ff = false;
                        if(!inPic) {
                            Console.WriteLine("Skipped frame : start expected");
                        }
                        inPic = false;
                    }
                    // We are inside a JPEG picture
                    else if(inPic) {
                        if(ff) {
                            frameBuffer.Add(0xff);
                            ff = false;
                        }
                        frameBuffer.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To give it a try, have a PictureBox in a Winforms application, then in a button_click:

```
var s = SynchronizationContext.Current;

// assuming pb is your PictureBox

await Start("http://whateverurlthatstreamsmjpegs.com", 
    img => {
        s.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(i => {
            if(pb.Image != null)
                pb.Image.Dispose();
            pb.Image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom((byte[])i);
        }), img);
    }, 1024, CancellationToken.None);
```

This is far from a professional MJPEG decoder and some bugs remains, but there is a much more improved version [I put in a gist](https://gist.github.com/Larry57/958bd61252a3f810b75d). The gist version also includes login and password capabilities to watch streams that comes from some IP cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Coding4Fun project on Ch9

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder